# Returning full model with errors

Tags: c#, api, validation, modelstate

Currently I have an api which is consumed by the frontend. When a request is invalid, the api returns the model state with a Bad Request like so:

```
return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

However the issue with the model state is that a dictionary with key value pair isn't good enough as trying to map these back on the frontend isn't providing any certainty. Take this as an example:

I have an array of `User`. When a request is made, this may have many `User`'s, in this example a request is made with 2 `User`'s, the 2nd has an invalid Username and so the model state is returned like so:

```
{
   "modelState":
    { 
       "request.Users[0].Username": ["This username is invalid."]
    }
}
```

This means, in order for me to know which `User` is incorrect on the frontend, I have to grab the index of Users.

Instead, to make it easier to map back to the front end I would like the same structure which was sent in the request to be sent in the response but with validation messages if there is any like so:

```
{
    users: [
    {},
    {},
    {
      username: ["This is invalid", "This is also too short"],
    }
  ]
}
```

I've never seen this before and so I'm struggling to find anything that already exist. Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Could you please provide the structure of the elements inside Users collection? And I suppose you would like to override username with an array instead of one single validation.

Comment: I encountered a same kind of problem (not exactly the same though). I ended up with creating an action filter which checked if there were any model state errors after the request has been executed and mapped to model state error to a custom model. Not sure this will help you though since it was a really specific case and you might be looking for a more general solution.